# vertical-align & line-height mystery

Tags: html, css

it just starts to driving me nuts because I can not understand why vertical-align of the following CSS template does work in an empty html file only:

```
<head>
<style>
        #mylist li {
                display: inline-block;
                list-style: none;
                text-align: center;
                height: 250px;
                padding: 5px;                   
        }
        #mylist .imgcont {
                height: 150px;
                width: 150px;
                line-height: 150px;
                border: 1px solid red;
                padding: 5px;
                overflow: hidden;       
        }
        #mylist img {
                height:120px;
                vertical-align:middle;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>
        <div class="imgcont">
          <img src="someimg.jpg" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="imgcont">
          <img src="anotherimg.jpg" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

- In an "empty" html, mean bare html template with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` at the top, **vertical-align does apply and image is vertically centered** in div container
- When I do a **verbatim copy** and insert into more complex html (style in header tag, ul-list at the top of body tag) **suddenly vertical-align is ignored** and image is placed at top of the container. Simply can not understand what can make the difference here.

I even tried to prepend style "clear:both" but without an effect.

Any idea ?

**UPDATE - added screenshots for both cases**
[image: vertical-align in plain html]
[image: above example merged with some complex html, vertical-align ignored]

Comment: In the 2nd example, the vertical-align is ignored and images are aligned to the top of the div container. By the same css/html code.

Comment: If you're satisfied with Rishi's answer, don't forget to accept it. If you want any further input into why your initial approach was breaking you'll need to provide the HTML for the case where the vertical-align is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the below code if it helps, else please provide some screenshot for what you are getting and what you expect..

```
#mylist .imgcont {
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            line-height: 150px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            padding: 5px;
            overflow: hidden; 
            display:table-cell;
            vertical-align:middle;
            text-align:center;     
    }
```

It gives me the below output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately `position:relative` makes no difference. I did updated question with example screenshots & description.

Comment: `vertical-align:middle;` is only applicable to inline sibling elements.

Comment: Thanks Rishi, `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` for the wrapper div did the trick.